# Permutations with restrictions (on a round table)

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Suppose 8 people are sitting in 8 chairs in a circle. They're playing
>   musical chairs.
>
> The music plays. They all get up and move.
>
> The music ends. They all sit down.
>
> How many ways can they sit such that nobody has the same person to
>   their right as they did in the first orientation?
>
> As usual for "round table" problems, the solution is invariant under
>   rotation - i.e. the actual seat does not matter, only relative
>   position.

I would appreciate any help on this problem. I have a feeling it would be easier to solve with inclusion-exclusion, but I can't quite define my sets correctly.

Comment: Arbitrarily choose a person and call them person $1$ (*e.g. pick the youngest*).  Going counter-clockwise around the table from where person $1$ started, label the rest of the people $2,3,\dots,8$ according to where they initially sat.  Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_8$ be the events where person $i$ still has person $i+1$ to his right, wrapping around so that $A_8$ is the event that person $8$ still has person $1$ to his right.  $A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots \cup A_8$ is the "bad" outcome, we want the opposite, but we can count this one more easily than the opposite via inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Now, consider $|A_1|, |A_1\cap A_2|$ and $|A_1\cap A_3|$ as examples.  In $A_1$ you have $2$ following $1$, so briefly imagine they are siamese twins joined at the hip, so you are going to in effect arrange seven *bodies* around a circular table (*despite the fact that they still count as eight people*).  Similarly, $|A_1\cap A_2|$ we can imagine that persons $1,2,$ and $3$ are all sharing the same body, like a three-headed ogre or siamese triplets, or however you need to justify this in your mind, so we have in effect *six* bodies to arrange.  Similarly $|A_1\cap A_3|$ we have six bodies...